# Problema con archivo de exportación en android 11

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sqlite

estoy intentando realizar una funcion de exportar una base de datos en android. El problema es que tengo en mi móvil android 11, entonces la etiqueta android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" no sirve.
Con un móvil con Android 10 la exportación se realiza correctamente pero sin embargo en android 11 he mirado la documentación y la línea android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" la ignora completamente. Me gustaría saber una solución a este problema ya que no sé cuál es el error
Me gustaría saber como solucionar este problema.
Muchas gracias.

Este es mi MainActivity

```
package com.example.biblioteca;
    
    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
    import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
    import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
    
    import android.Manifest;
    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdaptadorLibro.OnDatosListener, FragmentoOrden.OrdenLista{
    
    
        ArrayList<Libro> listaLibros = new ArrayList<>();
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        TextView registros, orden;
        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper conexion;
        AdaptadorLibro adapter;
        int posicion;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
            registros = findViewById(R.id.tv_registros);
            orden = findViewById(R.id.tv_orden);
    
            //iniciamos conexion
            conexion = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "biblioteca", null, 1);
    
            pedirPermisos();
            guardarDatos();
    
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            adapter = new AdaptadorLibro(listaLibros, this, this);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    
        }
    
        //METODO PARA EL MENÚ
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }
        //METODO PARA EL MENÚ
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.item_alta:
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityAlta.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;
                case R.id.item_ordenar:
                    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentoOrden ffo = new FragmentoOrden();
                    ffo.show(fm, "ORDEN_LISTA");
                    break;
                case R.id.item_exportar:
                    exportar();
                    break;
                case R.id.item_importar:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "importar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                default:
            }
            return true;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onDatosBorrar(int posicion) {
    
            int id = listaLibros.get(posicion).getId();
            SQLiteDatabase db = conexion.getWritableDatabase();
            db.execSQL("delete from libros where id = " + id);
            db.close();
            listaLibros.remove(posicion);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            registros.setText("Número registros: " + listaLibros.size());
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onDatosEditar(int posicion) {
    
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityModificacion.class);
            i.putExtra("DATOS_MODIFICAR" , listaLibros.get(posicion));
            this.posicion = posicion;
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void ordenlista(String valor) {
            switch (valor){
                case "Fecha fin":
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "orden con" + valor, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case "Valoracion":
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "orden con " + valor, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                default:
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Libro l = (Libro) data.getExtras().getSerializable("DATOS_MODIFICADOS");
                listaLibros.set(posicion, l);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    
        public void guardarDatos(){
    
            SQLiteDatabase db = conexion.getReadableDatabase();
            Libro libro = null;
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from libros;", null);
    
            while(c.moveToNext()){
                libro = new Libro();
                libro.setId(c.getInt(0));
                libro.setCategoria(c.getString(1));
                libro.setTitulo(c.getString(2));
                libro.setAutor(c.getString(3));
                libro.setIdioma(c.getString(4));
                libro.setPrestado(c.getString(5));
                libro.setFormato(c.getString(6));
                libro.setNotas(c.getString(7));
                libro.setFecha_lectura_ini(c.getLong(8));
                libro.setFecha_lectura_fin(c.getLong(9));
                libro.setValoracion(c.getFloat(10));
    
                listaLibros.add(libro);
            }
            registros.setText("Número registros: " + listaLibros.size());
            c.close();
        }
    
        public void exportar() {
            File carpeta = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Biblioteca");
    
            boolean isCreateCarpeta = false;
            if(!carpeta.exists()) {
                isCreateCarpeta = carpeta.mkdir();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Existe la carpeta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    
            String archivo = carpeta + "/Libros.csv";
            /*boolean isCreate = false;
            if(!archivo.exists()) {
                isCreate = archivo.mkdir();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Existe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No existe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }*/
    
            checkExternalStoragePermission();
    
            try {
    
                FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(archivo);
                conexion = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "biblioteca", null, 1);
                SQLiteDatabase db = conexion.getWritableDatabase();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Buenas", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Cursor fila = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM libros", null);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, fila.toString() + " a " + fila.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
                if(fila != null && fila.getCount() != 0) {
                    fila.moveToFirst();
                    do {
                        fileWriter.append(fila.getInt(0) + " \n");
                        fileWriter.append(fila.getString(1) + " \n");
                        fileWriter.append(fila.getString(2) + " \n");
                        fileWriter.append(fila.getString(3) + " \n");
                    } while(fila.moveToNext());
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No hay registros", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
    
                fila.close();
                db.close();
                fileWriter.close();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Se creó exitosamente el archivo CSV", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                Log.i("Mensaje", e.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        public void pedirPermisos() {
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 0);
            }
        }
    
        private void checkExternalStoragePermission() {
            int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para leer.");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
            } else {
                Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para leer!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Este es el Androidmanifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.biblioteca">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE " />
    
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Biblioteca"
            android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:exported="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".ActivityAlta"
                android:exported="true">
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".ActivityModificacion"
                android:exported="true">
            </activity>
    
        </application>
    
    </manifest>
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con el directorio Android/data/<Package name>/files/Biblioteca? La línea de código de File carpeta = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/Biblioteca"); me ha ayudado, pero ahora no consigo saber donde se crea el fichero. He mirado en el directorio Android/data de mi móvil (Android 11) pero no se crea nada y no entiendo a lo que te refieres con <Package name> en la línea del directorio. Me gustaría conseguir arreglar todo esto ya que le he dedicado mucho tiempo.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

El uso de `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` era para ser usado temporalmente, ya que desde que orientabamos nuestra aplicación a Android 10 (nivel de API 29) o versiones anteriores se podía inhabilitar temporalmente el almacenamiento específico de la app de producción que se realizaba usando  [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory())).

> El problema es que tengo en mi móvil android 11, entonces la etiqueta
> android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" no sirve.

**Tu aplicación esta orientada a Android 11 o posterior, por esta razón ya no funcionará tu código, debes cambiar [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()) por el uso de [getExternalFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)).** Muy importante comentar que ahora al usar [getExternalFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) tus archivos o directorios se crearan dentro de la estructura:

```
Android/data/<Package name>/files/
```

tu código cambiaría:

```
 //File carpeta = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Biblioteca");
 File carpeta = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/Biblioteca");
```

y el directorio se debería leer en la siguiente ruta :

```
Android/data/<Package name>/files/Biblioteca
```